# Google Translate "swap language" button destroys original source text

Tags: google-translate

The "Swap Language" button (the left-right arrows) is behaving badly. It swaps the text across in the translated form and loses the original text in the process.

Browser back button does nothing.

I want to be able to have text from two languages on the left so I can make suggestions that will get Google to give a predictable bidirectional result that lets me know that I have found a credible match. I can no longer do this without pasting my working text repeatedly into the left box as I switch between the language directions.

Anyone know if there is a work around?

The browser warns that the old version of Adobe Flash is disabled but this has always been the case and I hope I can leave it so.

**EDIT:**
I tried it again with Adobe Flash turned on and there was no change.  Javascript was already turned on in FireFox.

I tried it with Opera browser that had JavaScript on with no Flash warning.  Symptoms were the same.

How to demonstrate the behaviour:

[Enter the following](https://translate.google.com/#en/fi/fir%0Asix%0Ayour%20moon%0Akuusi) into the source language box

```
fir
six
your moon
kuusi
```

Select **English > Finnish** translation
Activate the **SWAP** feature, and all original context is lost, activate **SWAP** again and all context is still lost.
The translate is moving text from side to side and I want to be able to just swap between translation direction, sometimes if I only have one language material in the source box I might want to move the result with the **SWAP** but I was able to do this with a **cut and paste** with minor effort when occasionally required.  The current functionality prevents me from using the **SWAP** feature without first saving the source data.

Comment: I suspect it's part of that scripting you're blocking. Turn off whatever's blocking it (if only temporarily) and see if it still happens.

Comment: @ale  This has changed recently last couple of weeks and my script settings have not been altered.  Test failed.